Please add the ability to edit posts in the discussion-space
While questions/answers in the discussion space are by design not held to the same rigorous standard of regular SO posts, the ability to edit posts should still exist, as people still:

do errors when tagging a post,
make typos,
are not always that good at English, making a post hard to read without fixing grammar/wording issues,
are sometimes not familiar with the markdown options, meaning the formatting has to be fixed.

Given the relative small amount of users active in the discussion space, I believe that a new suggest-edit review queue for discussions would not be feasible, nor adding discussion-suggest-edits to the regular suggest-edit queue. (As far as I understand if you edit your own post, there is no review if you are under 2k reputation points.)
Instead, I propose to only allow editing in discussions to users with the edit-privilege.

If not posts, then at least titles and tags.

The downside to allowing more people to edit is that there are basically no tools for moderating Discussion edits (like locks on the main site, or even a rollback button) and the people doing the moderation usually aren't SO mods (and therefore have to request a user be banned).

Valid concerns by Laurel. Not ideal, but if we even could let users above 25k edit just tags and titles, then it would at least look a tad cleaner.  I don't wanna ask for mod tools, cause I am not sure the feature is here to stay, so I'd rather support something that would require very little effort, with minimal (possible) side effects, than asking for the ideal tooling which would need serious dev time allotted.
